# How to prove $L(s, \chi_0 \chi^*) = 0$ if and only if $L(s, \chi^*) = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character modulo $q$ and 
suppose $\chi = \chi_0 \chi^*$ where $\chi_0$ is the principal character mod $q$ and $\chi^*$ is the primitive character inducing $\chi$.
I am wondering how can one prove that  $L(s, \chi) = 0$ if and only if  $L(s, \chi^*) = 0$? (I am only interested in $s$ in the critical strip)
Any comments are appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### $$\begin{aligned}L(s,\chi_0 \chi^{\ast}) &= \prod_p \frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}} \\ &= \prod_{p\mid q} \frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}} \prod_{p\nmid q} \frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}} \\
&= \prod_{p\mid q} \frac{1}{1-\chi(p)p^{-s}} \prod_{p \nmid  q} \frac{1}{1-\chi^{\ast}(p)p^{-s}} \\
&= L(s,\chi^{\ast})\prod_{p\mid q} ({1-\chi^\ast(p)p^{-s}}) \end{aligned}$$

So the two $L$-functions differ by an elementary factor that is nonzero in the critical strip.

Comment: Does the fact that the two $L$ functions differ by a constant hold for the critical strip as well? (I was just wondering because the Euler product is only valid for real part greater than 1...) Could you possibly explain this bit as well? Thank you very much.

Comment: By analytic continuation, the two $L$-functions differ by a constant throughout the whole complex plane (except the pole of course).

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think there is some error with the equations here.

Comment: @JohnnyT.  Thank you for pointing this out. I corrected it.

Comment: So it turns out that the relation is not if and only if because the extra factor can introduce some zeros for the imprimitive one (which does not occur for the primitive one) but it only occur on the Re = 0 line.